# Using UI-Router to split up parts of a big data entry form

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, parent-child

I have a big data entry form that's defined programmatically.

I'm modeling it with a PlanController.
On launch, the PlanController loads the plan, its sections, and fields.
The PlanController's template shows:

1. the plan **header** information
2. a **navbar** loaded from the plan's sections, like this:

   ```
   li.nav-item(ng-repeat="section in plan.sections | filter:{'active': '1'}" ui-sref-active="active")
     a.nav-link(ui-sref="plan.section({idSection: section.idSectionDef})" ) {{sexion.title}}
   ```

***This is all working great.***

*Note: Since I don't know what sections there are beforehand, or what the fields in them are, I decided to use a ui-router child route to display the information section information.*

### This where I run into problems

All the **Plan** information is loaded in the parent Controller. I'm not sure how to bind the child information in the child view to the parent to the parent.

#### First Try - no child controller

I've tried declare the child (section) state without a controller, and try to access the section information directly from the PlanController:

```
 .state('plan.section', {
    url: '/section/{idSection}',
    templateUrl: 'app/plan/planSection.html'
  })
```

but in binding the section fields in the child state's template, planSection.html :

```
div.col-md-4.col-sm-12
  ilp-field(ng-repeat="fld in getFields($stateParams.idSection)| filter:{ layoutColumn: 10, idSectionDef: $stateParams.idSection}"  datafield="fld" )
div.col-md-8.col-sm-12
  ilp-field(ng-repeat="fld in getFields($stateParams.idSection) | filter:{ layoutColumn: 20}"  datafield="fld" onchangecallback="checkilp")
```

I get the fields for the first section (*$scope.getFields takes a section id and returns a list of fields that belong to that section*).

When I select one of the other child sections, the **url** is showing the change of states, but the **fields** are not changing.

#### Second Try - child controller

I originally tried declaring the child state with its own controller:

```
  .state('plan.section', {
    url: '/section/{idSection}',
    templateUrl: 'app/plan/planSection.html',
    controller: 'planSectionController'
  })
```

but I don't know how to get the list of fields from the parent to the child control, and when I try to bind to:

```
    $state.$current.parent
```

as in

```
  ilp-field(ng-repeat="fld in $state.$current.parent.getFields($stateParams.idSection)| filter:{ layoutColumn: 10, idSectionDef: $stateParams.idSection}"  datafield="fld" )
```

I get an error that $state.$current.parent is not accessible.

---

### Would welcome some guidance on the right design pattern to use here with **ui-router**